# Renaming existing Azue Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I would like to move my existing Azure Data Factory from one resource group to another but with new name.

Is there a way to change ADF name before moving or post moving. This is required to adhere to the azure resource naming policy enforced at account level.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is possible to rename an existing Azure Data Factory.

However an alternate solution would be to copy or clone an Azure Data Factory. You can find more information about copy/clone Azure Data Factory here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-clone-data-factory.

One of the use cases mentioned in this link is exactly that:

> **Renaming resources**. Azure doesn't support renaming resources. If you want to rename a data factory, you can clone the data factory with
>   a different name, and then delete the existing one.

Comment: Oops just realized we posted at nearly identical times :)

Comment: :) Almost identical times.

Comment: just wanted to make sure you are informed, check my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to existing answers: that is not true or not entirely true. ARM supports renaming resources (just create an **application insights** resource and test that). But the resource providers (most of them anyway) dont support that.

Azure Data Factory doesnt support renames.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know that...guess I missed the memo :D. Can you share a link where I can read more about it?

Comment: I dont think you will find this in the docs anywhere. at least I found out about it randomly while working with appinsights. and then talked to the person from the ARM team in MS

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the unique name given to an Azure resource, though you *can* move something to a different resource group.

To get a new name, you'd need to redeploy your Data Factory assets (pipelines, etc) to a new Azure Data Factory.

Comment: just wanted to make sure you are informed, check my answer :)

Comment: Hmmmmmm very interesting. I'm guessing you can only rename resources that don't have an associated dns name assigned to it (such as Application Insights). Good observation.

Comment: as far as I know this is up to the RP to implement. I suppose any RP can implement that, they just choose not to. With the global dns names it would be harder to implement, but at the end of the day, shouldn't be much of a difference

Answer (score 0):

If you have not done so already add your current Data Factory to Git Repo eg MyOldDataFactory.
Clone the repo to a new repo myNewDataFactory
Create a new DataFactory with the correct name where ever you need it and hook it up to the cloned Git Repo myNewDataFactory repo.

You will need to fix all the links to Key Vaults and Shared Integration services etc but at least you will get all of your code and changes you make to fix your New Data Factory are save in your new repo and do not corrupt your old Git repo or old Data Factory.